# JBoss 4.2 consumindo SOA (barramento) com SSL

Tags: soap, ssl, certificado-digital, jboss, soa

Tenho que colocar uma aplicação que hoje está rodando em **Websphere** para rodar em **JBoss 4.2**.

Acontece que a aplicação consome serviços do **SOA (SOAP)** por **Barramento** via **HTTPS** e ai está o problema que estou enfrentando.

De posse do certificado, eu gerei uma **Keystore** onde armazenei a chave, configurei o  **server.xml** da aplicação e inclusive configurei o **properties-service.xml**.

Já tomei vários erros que inclusive vou colocar abaixo:

```
INFO  [ChaveIntegracaoAspect] Início Integração SERVICO_CONSULTA_XPTO -documento: F=99999999999 -tipoIdentificacao: 2
INFO  [ChaveIntegracaoAspect] Fim Integração SERVICO_CONSULTA_XPTO -documento: F=99999999999 -erro: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
ERROR [ChaveIntegracaoAspect] Erro na Integração SERVICO_CONSULTA_XPTO -documento: F=99999999999 -erro: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

INFO  [ChaveIntegracaoAspect] Início Integração SERVICO_CONSULTA_XPTO -documento: F=9999999999 -tipoIdentificacao: 2
INFO  [ChaveIntegracaoAspect] Fim Integração SERVICO_CONSULTA_XPTO -documento: F=9999999999 -erro: null
ERROR [ChaveIntegracaoAspect] Erro na Integração SERVICO_CONSULTA_XPTO -documento: F=9999999999 -erro: null
INFO  [ChaveIntegracaoAspect] Fim Integração SERVICO_CONSULTA_XPTO -documento: F=9999999999
ERROR [CadastroPessoaProvider] [4e546712] Erro ao consultar o CPF 9999999999 - Exception: null - com.xpto.xptoprint.client.util.ConfigWebService.incluirConfiguracoesDefaultWebserviceJAXWS(155);   com.xpto.xptoprint.client.util.ConfigWebService.incluirConfiguracoesDefaultComAutenticacaoWebserviceJAXWS(124); ....    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(446)
```

Depois de configurar o **properties-service.xml**

```
INFO  [ChaveIntegracaoAspect] Fim Integração CONSULTA_RESGATE_XPTO -documento: F=9999999999 -erro: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
ERROR [ChaveIntegracaoAspect] Erro na Integração CONSULTA_RESGATE_XPTO -documento: F=9999999999 -erro: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
INFO  [ChaveIntegracaoAspect] Fim Integração CONSULTA_RESGATE_XPTO -documento: F=9999999999
ERROR [ResgatePontoCartaoServiceProvider] [5ab5b336] com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
INFO  [ChaveIntegracaoAspect] Início Integração SERVICO_XPTO -documento: F=9999999999 -tipoIdentificacao: 2
INFO  [ChaveIntegracaoAspect] EntradaIntegracaoXpto [cpf=9999999999
INFO  [ChaveIntegracaoAspect] Fim Integração SERVICO_XPTO -documento: F=9999999999 -erro: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
ERROR [ChaveIntegracaoAspect] Erro na Integração SERVICO_XPTO -documento: F=9999999999 -erro: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
INFO  [ChaveIntegracaoAspect] Fim Integração SERVICO_XPTO -documento: F=9999999999
ERROR [CartaoEaiFacadeImpl] [5ab5b336] com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
INFO  [ChaveIntegracaoAspect] Início Integração SERVICO_CONSULTA_SEGURADO -documento: F=9999999999 -tipoIdentificacao: 2
INFO  [ChaveIntegracaoAspect] Fim Integração SERVICO_CONSULTA_SEGURADO -documento: F=9999999999 -erro: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
ERROR [ChaveIntegracaoAspect] Erro na Integração SERVICO_CONSULTA_SEGURADO -documento: F=9999999999 -erro: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
INFO  [ChaveIntegracaoAspect] Fim Integração SERVICO_CONSULTA_SEGURADO -documento: F=9999999999
ERROR [CadastroPessoaProvider] [5ab5b336] Erro ao consultar o CPF 9999999999 - Exception Caused By: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty - sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(208);    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(1884); 
INFO  [PPWHttpSessionListener] [556ba663] Sessão Destruída:  ID: A4F91CA9A024110B0406DBAC1E34A727 >>DATA/HORA: 30/05/2019 17:06 []
```

Simplesmente preciso consumir um serviço SOA que está exposto com https e não encontro uma solução.

Comment: Solução abaixo!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui a resposta para a pergunta acima.

**Tutorial**

Fazer download do arquivo da classe **InstallCert.java**

**Compilar a classe**

```
javac InstallCert.java
```

**Acesse o servidor e recupere o certificado (aceite o certificado padrão 1)**

```
java InstallCert [host]:[port]
```

**Exemplo:**

```
java InstallCert java InstallCert barramento.com.br:443
```

**Copiar a keystore *jssecacerts* para a pasta security do Java**

```
"jssecacerts" para "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\lib\security\"
```

**Extrair certificado do keystore jssecacerts criado**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias [host]-1 -keystore jssecacerts -storepass changeit -file [host].cer
```

**Exemplo:**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias barramento.com.br-1 -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\lib\security\jssecacerts" -storepass changeit -file barramento.com.br.cer
```

**Importar certificado para o keystore do sistema**

```
keytool -importcert -alias [host] -keystore [path to system keystore] -storepass changeit -file [host].cer
```

**Exemplo:**

```
keytool -importcert -alias barramento.com.br -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -file barramento.com.br.cer
```

Repositório para download do **InstallCert**

https://github.com/escline/InstallCert

Funcionou!!!